# JS click event handlers and GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get something working in GTM but I probably misunderstood the inner workings. Here's what I try to do.

I have a tag that is loaded on the relevant page:

```
<script>

  document.querySelector('#btnNext').addEventListener('click', {{EPT - Handler}}, false);
  document.querySelector('#btnPrev').addEventListener('click', {{EPT - Handler}}, false);
  
</script>
```

and I have defined the {{EPT - Handler}} as a Variable of type custom javascript as follows:

```
function() {
    return function (event) {
        console.log('EVH ', event);
    }
}
```

This works the first time I click on one of the buttons. If I look into the attached events before the click, I see that there are three events attached, among them, the above handler. Then I click, the console.log() is executed and all seems well. But when I now look at the handlers, there are only 2 of them and the one above is missing. Of course now when I click, the above handler isn't called anymore.

What am I missing here?

**The bigger picture**
Currently I have a number of Tags that send events to GA depending on what was clicked inside an SPA. Each Tag has its own Trigger.

I thought I'd just wire up all the buttons with one event handler instead and have that event handler put the stuff that should go to GA into the dataLayer where it finally gets sent as result of the customEvent I put in the dataLayer. I'd have a much smaller number of tags and triggers (1 tag, 1 trigger) so I have a simpler setup than currently.

Now, after explaining all of this, I'm pretty sure I don't need this custom JS event listener at all :)

Still I would be interested in who deletes my event listener...

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what is the expected behavior? Why you use `function() { return function (event) {` instead of simply `function(event) {` ?

Comment: The expected behavior would be that the handler works on every click I make, not only the first. I've been trying a number of different variants prior to that anonymous function that returns the handler function. This particular variant is something that I've seen quite often in GTM tutorials.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the expected format for a custom javascript variable in GTM is an anonymous function that does not take parameters and returns something. So that is not the problematic bit.

Comment: The only reason to use code as in you example is if you need access to the actual "event" properties. For anything else, creating your own event handlers instead of using the built-in click handlers is a bad idea. So can we first make sure that this is actually you use case?

Comment: @EikePierstorff that's a very good question. I was pondering this over the weekend as well tbh. I don't need the actual event data, no. I just thought it was a simpler approach to wire this up in JS and have one larger function that puts stuff in the datalayer depending on what was clicked on. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot see your actual page, I make an educated guess. Probably your next/previous buttons update a part of your page via some sort of Ajax call. If they are themselves replaced with updated content, the event handler is lost.

The click handlers in Google Tag Manager works around such problems by not attaching events to the element directly. Instead handlers are attached to the document directly. If a link is clicked the event bubbles up to the document. The handler attached to the document inspects the original event target, and if it meets the configured conditions they fire the respective triggers. This approach also works on dynamically inserted/replaced elements.

A bit of guesswork as I don't see your page, but at least a theory you can check.

Comment: I cannot show the page but you helped me get on the right track. I didn't pursue this line of thought first, as I had no idea that GTM attaches its clickers to the document directly. Now everything fell into place :) I'm now attaching the click event handler to the outer container myself and check on every click if one of the buttons has been hit. THANKS!